# NetBeans automation?

Tags: netbeans

Did anyone go from VS to NB?

Is there a functionality in NetBeans (I have v8.2 a portable 32 bit) like External Tools similar to these known from Visual Studio? Here is a explanation: http://wiki.netbeans.org/ExternalTools , but I have not this menu item in my NB.

And yet I didn't found in NB VS-like PostBuil and PreBuild events on the Project level (launching specified scripts or executables before or after build).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use **QuickOpener** plugin:

[Plugin portal link](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/62668/?show=true)

[Project home](https://github.com/dzsessona/QuickOpener-NetBeans)

Comment: It works. Maybe a bit hard to configure but solves one of my needs. If one wanna to launch a script must to write like cmd /c start drive:\path\script.bat ${fileNameExt} or so on. I could not run the command itself like eg "echo 'sth' & pause" or "cmd /c echo 'sth' & pause" or even "cmd" itself. But can live. Thanks.